# How to get number pattern like "#123456789" from dialing button

Tags: android

I have tried using the following code piece:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)){             
    String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);                     
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
    bundle.putInt("hideAppPass", Integer.parseInt(number));
    Log.e("number ",number+"");         
}
```

but it says "NUmberFormateException".

Updated code:

```
public class HideAppIconReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

 Log.e("app icon receiver ", "onReceive()+");

    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)){

        String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        if (number == null){
        Log.e("Error entering number ", "number is null "+ number+"");
        }else{
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("hideAppPass", Integer.parseInt(number));
            Log.e("number ",number+"");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Error Log :

```
09-05 12:12:00.070 3178-3178/applock.mindorks.com.applock E/app icon receiver: onReceive()+
09-05 12:12:00.070 3178-3178/applock.mindorks.com.applock E/Error entering number: number is null null
```

Comment: first check for null then pass to bundle and post your error log too?

Comment: If your "number" contains #, it's not a number anymore, so you can't use Integer.parseInt

Comment: Thanks all of you for Quick response.  I managed to solve it.